# NullPointerException on an array of strings

Tags: arrays, string, nullpointerexception

My purpose is to get what a user types in and to store them in the array "info", then convert the info[0] into upper case. However, when I compile my code, I always got the message Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at the line "info[0]=info[0].toUpperCase();". But I totally have not idea what causes this exception. If anyone can tell me the cause, it would be great. Thank you!

```
        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {        
            Scanner userScan = new Scanner(System.in);
            String keyboard = userScan.nextLine();
            StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(keyboard, " ");
            String[] info= new String[4];

            for(int i=0; tokens.hasMoreTokens(); i++)
            {
                info[i] = tokens.nextToken();
            }
            info[0]=info[0].toUpperCase();

            //other codes...

        }
```

Comment: if you press enter at the beginning, the input will be null. Except this the code is running fine.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to execute the code without any tokens, It would skip past the for loop, and try to perform

```
info[0].toUpperCase();
```

But since the for loop has been skipped info object is initialized to null.

Thus trying to access it would give you an Null Pointer Exception.

Just move the conversion inside the for loop to avoid this.

```
    for(int i=0; tokens.hasMoreTokens(); i++){
        info[i] = tokens.nextToken();
        //converts only when value exists
        info[i]=info[i].toUpperCase();
    }
```